# Unable to install docker on a fresh debian 8 jessie

Tags: installation, docker, debian, apt

I'm trying to install docker-engine on a fresh debian 8 (jessie). I followed the instructions listed [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/debian/#debian-jessie-80-64-bit).
Unfortunately, docker-engine fails to install using apt, and after having wasted so many hours trying to solve this I have absolutely no idea what to do next. I also tried to install version 1.9.0-0~jessie, but this generates the same errors.

uname -a:

```
Linux seven 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u3 (2015-08-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is what happens when I try to install:

```
berten@seven:~$ sudo apt-get install docker-engine  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
The following extra packages will be installed:  
  aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount git git-man libapparmor1 liberror-perl libnih-dbus1 libnih1 makedev mountall patch
  plymouth  
Suggested packages:  
  git-daemon-run git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-arch git-cvs git-mediawiki
  git-svn ed diffutils-doc desktop-base plymouth-themes  
The following NEW packages will be installed:  
  aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount docker-engine git git-man libapparmor1 liberror-perl libnih-dbus1 libnih1 makedev
  mountall patch plymouth  
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.  
Need to get 13.0 MB of archives.  
After this operation, 62.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]   
Get:1 http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ jessie/main makedev all 2.3.1-93 [42.6 kB]  
Get:2 http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ jessie/main plymouth amd64 0.9.0-9 [189 kB]  
Get:3 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie/main docker-engine amd64 1.9.1-0~jessie [7,344 kB]  
Get:4 http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ jessie/main libnih1 amd64 1.0.3-4.3 [127 kB]  
Get:5 http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ jessie/main libnih-dbus1 amd64 1.0.3-4.3 [97.1 kB]  
Get:6 http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ jessie/main mountall amd64 2.54 [68.3 kB]  
Get:7 http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ jessie/main patch amd64 2.7.5-1 [109 kB]  
Get:8 http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ jessie/main aufs-tools amd64 1:3.2+20130722-1.1 [92.9 kB]  
Get:9 http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ jessie/main cgroupfs-mount all 1.1 [4,572 B]  
Get:10 http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ jessie/main liberror-perl all 0.17-1.1 [22.4 kB]  
Get:11 http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ jessie/main git-man all 1:2.1.4-2.1 [1,266 kB]  
Get:12 http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ jessie/main git amd64 1:2.1.4-2.1 [3,624 kB]  
Get:13 http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ jessie/main libapparmor1 amd64 2.9.0-3 [60.3 kB]  
Fetched 13.0 MB in 1s (7,787 kB/s)          
Selecting previously unselected package makedev.  
(Reading database ... 86075 files and directories currently installed.)  
Preparing to unpack .../makedev_2.3.1-93_all.deb ...  
Unpacking makedev (2.3.1-93) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package plymouth.  
Preparing to unpack .../plymouth_0.9.0-9_amd64.deb ...  
Unpacking plymouth (0.9.0-9) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package libnih1.  
Preparing to unpack .../libnih1_1.0.3-4.3_amd64.deb ...  
Unpacking libnih1 (1.0.3-4.3) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package libnih-dbus1.  
Preparing to unpack .../libnih-dbus1_1.0.3-4.3_amd64.deb ...  
Unpacking libnih-dbus1 (1.0.3-4.3) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package mountall.  
Preparing to unpack .../mountall_2.54_amd64.deb ...  
Unpacking mountall (2.54) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package patch.  
Preparing to unpack .../patch_2.7.5-1_amd64.deb ...  
Unpacking patch (2.7.5-1) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package aufs-tools.  
Preparing to unpack .../aufs-tools_1%3a3.2+20130722-1.1_amd64.deb ...  
Unpacking aufs-tools (1:3.2+20130722-1.1) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package cgroupfs-mount.  
Preparing to unpack .../cgroupfs-mount_1.1_all.deb ...  
Unpacking cgroupfs-mount (1.1) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package liberror-perl.  
Preparing to unpack .../liberror-perl_0.17-1.1_all.deb ...  
Unpacking liberror-perl (0.17-1.1) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package git-man.  
Preparing to unpack .../git-man_1%3a2.1.4-2.1_all.deb ...  
Unpacking git-man (1:2.1.4-2.1) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package git.  
Preparing to unpack .../git_1%3a2.1.4-2.1_amd64.deb ...  
Unpacking git (1:2.1.4-2.1) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package libapparmor1:amd64.  
Preparing to unpack .../libapparmor1_2.9.0-3_amd64.deb ...  
Unpacking libapparmor1:amd64 (2.9.0-3) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package docker-engine.  
Preparing to unpack .../docker-engine_1.9.1-0~jessie_amd64.deb ...  
Unpacking docker-engine (1.9.1-0~jessie) ...  
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...  
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u2) ...  
Processing triggers for dbus (1.8.20-0+deb8u1) ...  
Setting up makedev (2.3.1-93) ...  
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.  
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.  
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.  
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.  
Setting up plymouth (0.9.0-9) ...  
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)  
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults  
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults  
Setting up libnih1 (1.0.3-4.3) ...  
Setting up libnih-dbus1 (1.0.3-4.3) ...  
Setting up mountall (2.54) ...  
Setting up patch (2.7.5-1) ...  
Setting up aufs-tools (1:3.2+20130722-1.1) ...  
Setting up cgroupfs-mount (1.1) ...  
Setting up liberror-perl (0.17-1.1) ...  
Setting up git-man (1:2.1.4-2.1) ...  
Setting up git (1:2.1.4-2.1) ...  
Setting up libapparmor1:amd64 (2.9.0-3) ...  
Setting up docker-engine (1.9.1-0~jessie) ...  
Job for docker.service failed. See 'systemctl status docker.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.  
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.  
dpkg: error processing package docker-engine (--configure):  
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1  
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u2) ...  
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.120) ...  
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64  
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u1) ...  
Processing triggers for dbus (1.8.20-0+deb8u1) ...  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 docker-engine  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

systemctl status docker.service

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine  
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)  
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2015-12-19 17:12:33 CET; 14min ago  
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com  
  Process: 4770 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  
 Main PID: 4770 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

apt-cache policy docker-engine

```
docker-engine:     
  Installed: 1.9.1-0~jessie     
  Candidate: 1.9.1-0~jessie     
Version table:  
     1.9.1-0~jessie 0  
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages  
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status  
     1.9.0-0~jessie 0  
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages  
     1.8.3-0~jessie 0  
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages  
     1.8.2-0~jessie 0  
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages  
     1.8.1-0~jessie 0  
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages  
     1.8.0-0~jessie 0  
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages  
     1.7.1-0~jessie 0  
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages  
     1.7.0-0~jessie 0  
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages  
     1.6.2-0~jessie 0  
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages  
     1.6.1-0~jessie 0  
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages  
     1.6.0-0~jessie 0  
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages  
     1.5.0-0~jessie 0  
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Can you check the logs for the docker unit with journalctl and post them as well?

Comment: @AndyShinn I am not familiar with journalctl. It outputs _No journal files were found._ I read the man pages for journalctl and journald.conf but don't understand how to get the logs you requested.

Comment: try this: http://boynux.com/docker-jessie/

Comment: @Boynux FYI, I got things working, more or less by following your instructions (see my answer). Maybe you have something meaningfull to add? Oh, and thank you BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference here is what I did to get things working...

I used [Boynux' instructions](http://boynux.com/docker-jessie/) from one of the comments in the OP and installing on a fresh jessie failed again.

*systemctl status docker.service*

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
       └─override.conf
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-01-28 03:48:32 CET; 9s ago
   Docs: https://docs.docker.com
Process: 7968 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// ${DOCEKR_OPTS} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 7968 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

After this I renamed */etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf* to */etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf.bak*, restarted systemd and the docker service and everything magically works!

Detailed steps:

```
curl https://get.docker.com | sh
sudo usermod -aG docker berten
touch /etc/default/docker
sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
systemctl status docker.service
sudo mv /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf.bak
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
systemctl status docker.service
```

So I guess with all unnecessary steps removed this should work too:

```
curl https://get.docker.com | sh
sudo usermod -aG docker berten
touch /etc/default/docker
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I'll try to see what causes that issue and update if I manage to find anything.